# PySpark: find if item is in top 5 popular

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have sales list like this (pySpark):

```
+---------+----------+
|productId|      date|
+---------+----------+
|      868|2020-11-01| 
|      878|2020-11-01| 
|      878|2020-11-01| 
|      913|2020-11-01|     
|      746|2020-11-01|     
|      878|2020-11-01|     
|      657|2020-11-02|        
|      746|2020-11-02|       
|      101|2020-11-02|       
+---------+----------+
```

So, I want to get a new column: item position by number of purchases. Most popular item of the day will have rank 1, etc. I've tried to implement window function, but can't figure out how to do it correctly. What is the best way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

count_per_day = F.count('productId').over(Window.partitionBy('date')).alias('count_per_day')
df = df.select('*', count_per_day)
rank = F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy('date').orderBy(F.col('count_per_day').desc())).alias('rank')
df = df.select('*', rank)
```

Comment: Thank you! But i changed first line to ... partitionBy('date', 'productId') ... and then it worked.